# Why can't I lint my create-react-app project with the eslint-config-rallycoding npm package?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I've been able to use the npm package `eslint-config-rallycoding` in multiple react and react native projects, but I run into issues when trying it with `create-react-app`. Are there additional steps I need to do?

Usually all that is needed is:

1. Create the project
2. `npm i --save-dev eslint-config-rallycoding`
3. touch .eslintrc
4. Add `{ "extends": "rallycoding" }` to the .eslintrc file

I am using sublime text 3 and this works with other projects just fine. I know create-react-app has a bunch of extra boilerplate, perhaps there's something I need to override?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-rallycoding
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: "I run into issues" - what?

Comment: Ah I guess that's important - It doesn't do any linting. No changes, errors, or any indication that I tried to setup a linter.

Comment: Does it work if you run it from the command line? `eslint path/to/your/file.js` ?

Comment: eslint src/App.js returns Cannot find module 'eslint-config-rallycoding', even though it's in the package.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the following lines in the create-react-app readme, I noticed there is already linting included:

> You would need to install an ESLint plugin for your editor first.
>   Then, add a file called `.eslintrc` to the project root:
>
> `js {   "extends": "react-app" }`
>
> Now your editor should report the linting warnings.

To customize it further with a specific linting package like the above, you would need to eject to run `npm run eject` which would remove the single build dependency from your project allowing customization to babel, webpack, and eslint files.